# Pandas rolling window bounds appear to be open even when closed='both'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm attempting to use BaseIndexer to define my own window bounds. However, I appear to be running into an off-by-one issue. I want to make sure I am reading the documentation right. The CustomIndexer code below is taken [from the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/user_guide/computation.html#custom-window-rolling).

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.api.indexers import BaseIndexer
import numpy as np


class CustomIndexer(BaseIndexer):
    def get_window_bounds(self, num_values, min_periods, center, closed, step):
        start = np.empty(num_values, dtype=np.int64)
        end = np.empty(num_values, dtype=np.int64)
        for i in range(num_values):
            if self.use_expanding[i]:
                start[i] = 0
                end[i] = i+1
            else:
                start[i] = i
                end[i] = i + self.window_size
        print(f'Start Bounds: {start}')
        print(f'End Bounds: {end}')
        return start, end

use_expanding = [True, False, True, False, True]
df = pd.DataFrame({'values': range(5)})

indexer = CustomIndexer(window_size=1, use_expanding=use_expanding)
print(df.rolling(indexer, closed='neither').sum())
print(df.rolling(indexer, closed='both').sum())
```

The bounds are -

```
Start Bounds: [0 1 0 3 0]
End Bounds: [1 2 3 4 5]
```

I get the same output for both `closed='neither'` and `closed='both'`.

```
values
0     0.0
1     1.0
2     3.0
3     3.0
4    10.0
```

I expect the following when `closed='both'` because the edges of window should be included in the summation.

```
values
0     1.0
1     3.0
2     6.0
3     7.0
4    10.0 (or NaN or error because 5 is an out of bounds index)
```

So, my question is, why is the right most datapoint of the Rolling window not being included in the sum?